# How to instruct Emacs auto-capitalize-mode not to capitalize after ellipsis, e.g., and i.e.?

Tags: emacs, org-mode

I use Emacs auto-capitalize-mode, which works perfectly most of the time except for `...` (ellipsis), and words like `e.g.` and `i.e.`.

If I write a sentence... and then another part... and then another part... auto-capitalize-mode mistakenly capitalizes it like so:

`"If I write a sentence... And then another part... And then another part..."`

How do I tell auto-capitalize-mode not to capitalize after ellipsis?

Same question for `e.g.` and `i.e.`

Comment: `auto-capitalize-mode` uses the Emacs default mechanism for determining the end of a sentence, which in turn relies on some regexps customizable in the paragraphs group; try `M-x customize-group RET paragraphs RET` and examine the values of the 'Sentence End.*' variables, in particular 'Sentence End Base'. I can't suggest a possible change to the value, but that'd be a likely place to start; if you need to change just the behavior of auto-capitalize-mode, rather than that of Emacs as a whole, you'd want to look at advising the function `auto-capitalize-sentence-end`.

Comment: Is there a way to make typing `e.g.` or `i.e.` automatically call a function? A function which would insert those characters and then automatically lowercase the following word?

Comment: Yup! Emacs abbrevs support hooks. The best way I know to define one is to `M-x edit-abbrevs`, which visits the abbrevs table list. Each abbrev is defined as NAME USECOUNT EXPANSION HOOK, where HOOK is empty by default; you'd define "i.e." as an abbrev which expands to itself, and whose hook finds the word following the abbrev and downcases it. Once you're done editing the abbrev table entry, `C-c C-c` will apply the change in your current session, and `C-x C-s` saves the file.

Comment: On the other hand, I've just discovered that Emacs abbrev-mode doesn't appear to support abbrevs containing (as opposed to ending with) punctuation, so defining e.g. "e.g." as an abbrev doesn't work; the expander fails to recognize it, so it neither gets replaced nor has its hook, if any, fired. I'm not sure how to fix that, but I suspect the best alternative is to use something like yasnippet-mode, which I gather offers both a more comprehensive recognizer, and more extensive and easily accessible expansion capabilities.

Comment: In any case, so that my effort doesn't go *entirely* to waste, here's what I came up with for a hook function which downcases the word following the expansion: `(lambda nil (save-excursion (forward-word) (push-mark) (backward-word) (downcase-region (point) (mark))))` Of course this only works on things Emacs recognizes as a "word", so a hyphenated compound, for example, would only have its first part downcased; if that's a concern, you probably want to replace this simple-minded effort with something that looks at whitespace and non-infix punctuation instead.

Comment: Can you provide the complete abbrev entry, including the initial word, the replacement word, and the hook? (Even though punctuation isn't supported?)

Comment: Sure! What I added to the abbrev table was basically this: `"e.g." 0 "e.g." (lambda nil (...))`, with the placeholder filled by the lambda given in my previous comment. FYI, entering `e.g.` into a buffer, followed by `C-x a i g` (INVERSE-ADD-GLOBAL-ABBREV), tries to add an abbrev on `g.`; `C-u 2 C-x a i g`, which should add an abbrev on the two "words" preceding point, instead tries to add an abbrev on `e.`. I'm not sure why that doesn't work the way it seems like it should, but the misbehavior might offer some insight, which is why I mention it here. Hope this helps!

Comment: @AaronMiller Could you please a complete answer so that we can get all the steps at a glance and upvote. :) Thanks.

Comment: @Anusha As far as I can tell, I didn't actually succeed in coming up with a solution for the problem, so that's why I didn't post an answer. If you've found a way to make something working out of my comments, then why not write up and post an answer of your own?

Comment: @AaronMiller Your answer suggested that it did work, with some changes to how e.g. is added to the abbrev file but the steps were not clear. Thats why asked. The answer added following this comment does work correctly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
(setq auto-capitalize-predicate
  (lambda () (not (looking-back
       "\\([Ee]\\.g\\|[Ii]\\.e\\|\\.\\.\\)\\.[^.]*" (- (point) 20)))))
```